# Google contributor profile, how to find a Google+ profile for it?

Tags: google-plus, google-maps

Suppose, I have a link of a contributor profile or their reviews: https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/123456{/reviews}

How can I find their Google+ profile? Is there a link to it at Google contributor's profile?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a retired webapp. P.S. This question was bumped by a new, deleted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no link, apparently, but if they've got a public G+ profile, you should be able to simply manipulate the URL.

Change

```
https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/123456{/reviews}
```

To

```
https://plus.google.com/123456
```

It works for my profile, at least.

This assumes, of course, that they have a G+ profile, and that you have the access to see it.

Comment: it may be not public?